# Should questions asking for files via download or email be flagged?

Tags: discussion, flagging, scope

A couple times recently I've been seeing questions asking for specific files to be shared via download links posted in the answers or via email. The latest example of this I've seen is [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69859/help-missing-unique-theme-metacity-for-gtk-2) asking for a GTK 2 theme when the original download link is dead.

Are these questions okay to ask? Or are they off-topic?

Comment: The example looks OK to me, though getting close to off-topic perhaps. Might be better to edit the question to make it more neutral -- e.g., "Does anyone know where I can get this theme?"  As long as it is free, not subject to legal issues, etc.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's probably okay. It's not great, but it's probably okay.